# fill datatable from php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

Thanks everyone solved by using  JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

hello i trying to fill up datatable from a php file the data is generator from database then use echo json
and handle the response from javascript here is the php file

```
<?php
global $wpdb; 
$db_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT dbtest.FName, dbtest.SName FROM dbtest");
echo json_encode($db_list);
exit;
?>
```

and here is how i trying to handle the data in javascript

```
<script>
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhttp.open("GET", "datatabletest.php")
xhttp.send()

http.onload = function() { 
var response = xhttp.responseText;
console.log(response);
//from here problem start

$('#example').DataTable({
    "data": response,
    "columns": [
      { "data": "FName" },
      { "data": "SName" }
    ]
});
}
</script>
```

but it alert error DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'FName' for row 0, column 0.

it looks like the data from response is null but in console it showing as
[{"FName":"test","SName":"test2"}]

so i have tried to copy this line from console and add it into a var like

```
var jsdata = [{"FName":"test","SName":"test2"}];
//then use
 $('#example').DataTable({
        "data": jsdata,
        "columns": [
          { "data": "FName" },
          { "data": "SName" }
        ]
    });
    }
```

and that worked so why it not working from the response what is missing to make it work like that

Comment: Have you checked what is logged by `console.log(response);`? My guess is you need to do `"SELECT FName, SName FROM dbtest"` (prepending dbtest. is not necessary since that's the current table anyway)

Comment: yes i checked it's same as jsdata

Comment: Not exactly; try `var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);` (you were passing a JSON string, not an array of objects)

Comment: ok thanks now it working the weird thing is i have already tried with json.parse before and didn't work but now it do maybe there was a mistake somewhere thanks you for helping me

Comment: to get column titles, adjust to: `"columns": [
      { "data": "FName","title":"Fname" },
      { "data": "SName","title":"Sname"  }
    ]`

Comment: thanks you i was able to add it direct on the table but this way is better